# CPU register for core migration

Tags: migration, cpu, cpu-registers

I'm studying about core migration in multi-core circumstance. And I have a question about that, what CPU registers are needed during migration.

For example, there are several cores in test machine. core 0 operates the specific program writing random value in memory for each cycle. So I intend to show that this program works normally.

When I try to migrate this process from core 0 to core 1, I'm not sure that which CPU registers are needed in this period. Of course, There are lots of CPU register : eax, ebx,... esp, esi (in manual of Intel reference) and so on. But I try to find absolutely essential value for migration.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I want to find essential CPU register for migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is no different than multiple processes on a single core.**

A process is a user-mode (ring 3) concept. Whenever your OS schedules a new process for execution, it has to restore the contents of *all* registers to the state that process left them in, the last time it executed.  This entire state is kept with each process as it is switched.

So when it comes to scheduling a process on a different core than the one it last ran on (migration), it's now different - the OS simply restores this register state to a different CPU core.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So you mean that all register in CPU are needed for migration and OS handle that process automatically?

Comment: Yes. As far as a process is concerned, it is the only thing running on a processor. So all of its registers should remain intact at all times, because the process could get swapped out at any point in its execution.